# Strange error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, mathptmx

Why does this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\coprod@}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"60}
\gdef\coprod{\DOTSB\coprod@\slimits@}
\let\DOTSB\relax
\let\slimits@\relax

\begin{document}
$\coprod$
\end{document}
```

generate:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./coprod@mu.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty)

./coprod@mu.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 ...ymbol{\coprod@}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"60}
```

and what should I do to fix it?

**Update:**
As the answers suggested, I'm missing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Adding them compiles to:
[image]
I would like:
[image]
How do I get that?

Comment: Your edit is really an entirely different question!

Comment: What should be the purpose of `\let\DOTSB\relax` and of `\let\slimits@\relax`? You're simply trying to break `amsmath`. Regarding the missing symbol: the fonts available with `mathptmx` don't have a coproduct symbol. It's available if you say `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Comment: I've already started reading the documentation and will probably make a package replacement. Does that package have `\imath` and `\jmath` as well, by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a brace of `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`, @ cannot be part of command names.

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol …
…
\let\slimits@\relax
\makeatother
```

seemed to work better for me (though I don't know what your intended result is – it compiled, at least).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `\makeatletter` before line 3 and `\makeatother` before `\begin{document}`. LaTeX tries to expand `@`-commands and so raise that error.